# question on multicols width and minipages difference in section vs. main document

Tags: minipage, multicol

I am trying to split a page into 2 halfs, using 2 minipages side by side.  So I made the following construct

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  stuff here
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  stuff here
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
```

Which seems to work very well, except I noticed inside a section I had to reduce the `0.45` value to keep the 2 minipages next to each others. So I am wondering why as I had thought `\textwidth` remains the same.

Here is an example which works, when outside a section

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I simply add a section, and kept everything the same, and it still works, as long as there is nothing before the cols

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%               
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}    
\section{foo}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I added one single letter before the 2 columns, and now the minipages are on top of each others

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%               
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\section{foo}
z

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I reduced the size of minipage from `0.45` to `0.4` then it worked again

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%               
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
z

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
   xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question is**: Why I had to reduce the size on minipage inside section to keep them side by side when adding a line before? does text width change depending on being in chapter, section, etc...?

**Appendix:**

I did try `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` thinking it was an indent thing, but it had no effect

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%               
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section{foo}
z

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
   xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know why `\noindent`  worked in the answer given below, but a global `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` did not!

Comment: Remove the space between the minipages. Though that isn't why.

Comment: @cfr I have space between them? I made sure to put % just to clear extra clear there is no space. hum... I will run  a HEX dump program in source code to check for a white space between, since I do not see it in the editor now. Thanks.

Comment: with your last example obviously you can not get two boxes each .45\textwidth and an interword space (which is the wrong space, which you have in all your examples) to fit side by side in a column that is itself less than .5\textwidth wide. why are you using multicols here?

Comment: of course there is a word space between them from the end of line after `\end{multicols}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is a long story why I am using multicols. It is only way to force tex4ht to split the page into 2 halfs. If I just use minipages side by side, tex4ht puts them on top of each others. So this is a trick to make tex4ht puts them side-by-side. So it looks like in the pdf file.

Comment: @Nasser it makes no sense:-) if you do do it at least make your minipages `\columnwidth` wide why make them .45\\textwidth which is either just less or just more than the column width depending on other settings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am always confused which to use, textwidth or linewidth or columnwidth or so many. I used 0.45 textwidth  which should give it plenty of margin to fit it there on the page. Latex has too many parameters.

Comment: There's a space at `\end{minipage}` because you haven't commented the line ending. The comment on the next line doesn't obliterate the space you just input. I can get the minipages to go on top of each other using `multicols` but I cannot get a difference depending on whether there is content before them, with or without `\parindent` at zero and with or without the interword space between the minipages. Either both cases are side-by-side or both are staked.

Comment: why do you say .45\textwidth should give plenty of margin to fit?, if it fits it's just by luck whether .45\textwidth is less than \columwidth which is (\textwidth-\columnsep)/2

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, with default `\columnsep` and the `\textwidth` in the example, there *is* more than sufficient space. It isn't just luck if you know this from experience.

Comment: @cfr yes I know but it is a crazy way to specify it and means the "columns" are skewed to the left as both minipages are to the left of the column so any difference between .45\textwidth and \columnwidth comes on the right. far better to use \columnwidth or better still don't use multicols

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I agree. I also suggested not using `multicols`. At best, it just complicates things.

Comment: If you want two side by side paragraphs in a way a translator to html understands why not just simply a two column table with two p columns, why all the complication of multicols?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I was trying to find an alternative to tables. Currently, table (long table) is the main tool I use to partition the page into 2 halfs) which works same way in pdf and HTML. I had few issues with table, and so just trying to see if I can find an alternative way, which might be better. That is why I am trying multicols with minipages.

Comment: no it's just wrong, just use a single row two column table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `\section` suppresses the indentation of the first paragraph, so

```
\section{foo}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
```

starts the first `minipage` at the left margin.

When you add content before the columns

```
\section{foo}
z
```

paragraph indentation is suppressed before that content. Then there's a paragraph break, so

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
   xxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}
```

the first `minipage` is indented as normal.

In your final example, you don't just change the width, you also zero the default paragraph indentation. But you don't need to - and almost certainly should not - do this. You can simply use `\noindent`.

```
\section{foo}
z

\noindent
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{minipage}
  %
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: kill indentation]

But the `multicols` environment is really not needed here. You can just use `minipage`s:

```
\section{bar}
a

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  yyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  yyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}
```

[image: kill indentation with minipages alone]

or

```
\section{foobar}
b

\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  zzzzzzzzzzz
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  zzzzzzzzzzz
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\fill}
```

[image: variant minipage spacing]

For comparison:

[image: comparison]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
z

\noindent
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{minipage}
  %
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    xxxxxxxxxxx
  \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}

\section{bar}
a

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  yyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  yyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}

\section{foobar}
b

\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  zzzzzzzzzzz
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  zzzzzzzzzzz
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I _did_ try `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` and it had no effect! I did not show this attempt to keep the question short. I can post the example now as appendix. That is why I was confused. It must be as you way `\section suppresses the indentation of the first paragraph,` which I did not know about. (so may rules to remember).

Comment: @Nasser Works fine for me if I remove the `\noindent`s and set `\parindent` to zero.

Comment: Please see example I just posted. I